# EF6 generates ridiculous SQL statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I may not be an SQL expert, but when doing performance tests, I have seen that EF6 (Code-First) generates the following statement:

```
SELECT 
[UnionAll3].[C2] AS [C1], 
[UnionAll3].[C3] AS [C2], 
[UnionAll3].[C4] AS [C3], 
[UnionAll3].[C5] AS [C4], 
[UnionAll3].[C6] AS [C5], 
[UnionAll3].[C7] AS [C6], 
[UnionAll3].[C8] AS [C7], 
[UnionAll3].[C1] AS [C8], 
[UnionAll3].[C9] AS [C9], 
[UnionAll3].[C10] AS [C10], 
[UnionAll3].[C11] AS [C11], 
[UnionAll3].[C12] AS [C12], 
[UnionAll3].[C13] AS [C13], 
[UnionAll3].[C14] AS [C14], 
[UnionAll3].[C15] AS [C15], 
[UnionAll3].[C16] AS [C16], 
[UnionAll3].[C17] AS [C17], 
[UnionAll3].[C18] AS [C18], 
[UnionAll3].[C19] AS [C19], 
[UnionAll3].[C20] AS [C20], 
[UnionAll3].[C21] AS [C21], 
[UnionAll3].[C22] AS [C22], 
[UnionAll3].[C23] AS [C23], 
[UnionAll3].[C24] AS [C24], 
[UnionAll3].[C25] AS [C25], 
[UnionAll3].[C26] AS [C26], 
[UnionAll3].[C27] AS [C27], 
[UnionAll3].[C28] AS [C28], 
[UnionAll3].[C29] AS [C29]
FROM  (SELECT 
    [UnionAll2].[C1] AS [C1], 
    [UnionAll2].[C2] AS [C2], 
    [UnionAll2].[C3] AS [C3], 
    [UnionAll2].[C4] AS [C4], 
    [UnionAll2].[C5] AS [C5], 
    [UnionAll2].[C6] AS [C6], 
    [UnionAll2].[C7] AS [C7], 
    [UnionAll2].[C8] AS [C8], 
    [UnionAll2].[C9] AS [C9], 
    [UnionAll2].[C10] AS [C10], 
    [UnionAll2].[C11] AS [C11], 
    [UnionAll2].[C12] AS [C12], 
    [UnionAll2].[C13] AS [C13], 
    [UnionAll2].[C14] AS [C14], 
    [UnionAll2].[C15] AS [C15], 
    [UnionAll2].[C16] AS [C16], 
    [UnionAll2].[C17] AS [C17], 
    [UnionAll2].[C18] AS [C18], 
    [UnionAll2].[C19] AS [C19], 
    [UnionAll2].[C20] AS [C20], 
    [UnionAll2].[C21] AS [C21], 
    [UnionAll2].[C22] AS [C22], 
    [UnionAll2].[C23] AS [C23], 
    [UnionAll2].[C24] AS [C24], 
    [UnionAll2].[C25] AS [C25], 
    [UnionAll2].[C26] AS [C26], 
    [UnionAll2].[C27] AS [C27], 
    [UnionAll2].[C28] AS [C28], 
    [UnionAll2].[C29] AS [C29]
    FROM  (SELECT 
        [UnionAll1].[C1] AS [C1], 
        [UnionAll1].[Id] AS [C2], 
        [UnionAll1].[Id1] AS [C3], 
        [UnionAll1].[Ident] AS [C4], 
        [UnionAll1].[DescriptionLong] AS [C5], 
        [UnionAll1].[DescriptionShort1] AS [C6], 
        [UnionAll1].[DescriptionShort2] AS [C7], 
        [UnionAll1].[ArticleGroup] AS [C8], 
        [UnionAll1].[Id2] AS [C9], 
        [UnionAll1].[Id3] AS [C10], 
        [UnionAll1].[Barcode] AS [C11], 
        [UnionAll1].[Amount] AS [C12], 
        [UnionAll1].[StorageLocation] AS [C13], 
        [UnionAll1].[Article_Id] AS [C14], 
        [UnionAll1].[C2] AS [C15], 
        [UnionAll1].[C3] AS [C16], 
        [UnionAll1].[C4] AS [C17], 
        [UnionAll1].[C5] AS [C18], 
        [UnionAll1].[C6] AS [C19], 
        [UnionAll1].[C7] AS [C20], 
        [UnionAll1].[C8] AS [C21], 
        [UnionAll1].[C9] AS [C22], 
        [UnionAll1].[C10] AS [C23], 
        [UnionAll1].[C11] AS [C24], 
        [UnionAll1].[C12] AS [C25], 
        [UnionAll1].[C13] AS [C26], 
        [UnionAll1].[C14] AS [C27], 
        [UnionAll1].[C15] AS [C28], 
        [UnionAll1].[C16] AS [C29]
        FROM  (SELECT 
            CASE WHEN ([Extent2].[Id] IS NULL) THEN CAST(NULL AS int) ELSE 1 END AS [C1], 
            [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
            [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id1], 
            [Extent1].[Ident] AS [Ident], 
            [Extent1].[DescriptionLong] AS [DescriptionLong], 
            [Extent1].[DescriptionShort1] AS [DescriptionShort1], 
            [Extent1].[DescriptionShort2] AS [DescriptionShort2], 
            [Extent1].[ArticleGroup] AS [ArticleGroup], 
            [Extent2].[Id] AS [Id2], 
            [Extent2].[Id] AS [Id3], 
            [Extent2].[Barcode] AS [Barcode], 
            [Extent2].[Amount] AS [Amount], 
            [Extent2].[StorageLocation] AS [StorageLocation], 
            [Extent2].[Article_Id] AS [Article_Id], 
            CAST(NULL AS int) AS [C2], 
            CAST(NULL AS int) AS [C3], 
            CAST(NULL AS int) AS [C4], 
            CAST(NULL AS decimal(18,2)) AS [C5], 
            CAST(NULL AS int) AS [C6], 
            CAST(NULL AS int) AS [C7], 
            CAST(NULL AS int) AS [C8], 
            CAST(NULL AS int) AS [C9], 
            CAST(NULL AS decimal(18,2)) AS [C10], 
            CAST(NULL AS datetime2) AS [C11], 
            CAST(NULL AS int) AS [C12], 
            CAST(NULL AS int) AS [C13], 
            CAST(NULL AS int) AS [C14], 
            CAST(NULL AS varchar(1)) AS [C15], 
            CAST(NULL AS int) AS [C16]
            FROM  [dbo].[Articles] AS [Extent1]
            LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[Batches] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[Id] = [Extent2].[Article_Id]
        UNION ALL
            SELECT 
            2 AS [C1], 
            [Extent3].[Id] AS [Id], 
            [Extent3].[Id] AS [Id1], 
            [Extent3].[Ident] AS [Ident], 
            [Extent3].[DescriptionLong] AS [DescriptionLong], 
            [Extent3].[DescriptionShort1] AS [DescriptionShort1], 
            [Extent3].[DescriptionShort2] AS [DescriptionShort2], 
            [Extent3].[ArticleGroup] AS [ArticleGroup], 
            CAST(NULL AS int) AS [C2], 
            CAST(NULL AS int) AS [C3], 
            CAST(NULL AS varchar(1)) AS [C4], 
            CAST(NULL AS decimal(18,2)) AS [C5], 
            CAST(NULL AS int) AS [C6], 
            CAST(NULL AS int) AS [C7], 
            [Extent4].[Id] AS [Id2], 
            [Extent4].[Id] AS [Id3], 
            [Extent4].[Amount] AS [Amount], 
            [Extent4].[PricePerUncorrectedUnit] AS [PricePerUncorrectedUnit], 
            [Extent4].[Type] AS [Type], 
            [Extent4].[Article_Id] AS [Article_Id], 
            CAST(NULL AS int) AS [C8], 
            CAST(NULL AS int) AS [C9], 
            CAST(NULL AS decimal(18,2)) AS [C10], 
            CAST(NULL AS datetime2) AS [C11], 
            CAST(NULL AS int) AS [C12], 
            CAST(NULL AS int) AS [C13], 
            CAST(NULL AS int) AS [C14], 
            CAST(NULL AS varchar(1)) AS [C15], 
            CAST(NULL AS int) AS [C16]
            FROM  [dbo].[Articles] AS [Extent3]
            INNER JOIN [dbo].[ScalePrices] AS [Extent4] ON [Extent3].[Id] = [Extent4].[Article_Id]) AS [UnionAll1]
    UNION ALL
        SELECT 
        3 AS [C1], 
        [Extent5].[Id] AS [Id], 
        [Extent5].[Id] AS [Id1], 
        [Extent5].[Ident] AS [Ident], 
        [Extent5].[DescriptionLong] AS [DescriptionLong], 
        [Extent5].[DescriptionShort1] AS [DescriptionShort1], 
        [Extent5].[DescriptionShort2] AS [DescriptionShort2], 
        [Extent5].[ArticleGroup] AS [ArticleGroup], 
        CAST(NULL AS int) AS [C2], 
        CAST(NULL AS int) AS [C3], 
        CAST(NULL AS varchar(1)) AS [C4], 
        CAST(NULL AS decimal(18,2)) AS [C5], 
        CAST(NULL AS int) AS [C6], 
        CAST(NULL AS int) AS [C7], 
        CAST(NULL AS int) AS [C8], 
        CAST(NULL AS int) AS [C9], 
        CAST(NULL AS int) AS [C10], 
        CAST(NULL AS decimal(18,2)) AS [C11], 
        CAST(NULL AS int) AS [C12], 
        CAST(NULL AS int) AS [C13], 
        [Extent6].[Id] AS [Id2], 
        [Extent6].[Id] AS [Id3], 
        [Extent6].[Amount] AS [Amount], 
        [Extent6].[Date] AS [Date], 
        [Extent6].[Article_Id] AS [Article_Id], 
        CAST(NULL AS int) AS [C14], 
        CAST(NULL AS int) AS [C15], 
        CAST(NULL AS varchar(1)) AS [C16], 
        CAST(NULL AS int) AS [C17]
        FROM  [dbo].[Articles] AS [Extent5]
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[Demands] AS [Extent6] ON [Extent5].[Id] = [Extent6].[Article_Id]) AS [UnionAll2]
UNION ALL
    SELECT 
    4 AS [C1], 
    [Extent7].[Id] AS [Id], 
    [Extent7].[Id] AS [Id1], 
    [Extent7].[Ident] AS [Ident], 
    [Extent7].[DescriptionLong] AS [DescriptionLong], 
    [Extent7].[DescriptionShort1] AS [DescriptionShort1], 
    [Extent7].[DescriptionShort2] AS [DescriptionShort2], 
    [Extent7].[ArticleGroup] AS [ArticleGroup], 
    CAST(NULL AS int) AS [C2], 
    CAST(NULL AS int) AS [C3], 
    CAST(NULL AS varchar(1)) AS [C4], 
    CAST(NULL AS decimal(18,2)) AS [C5], 
    CAST(NULL AS int) AS [C6], 
    CAST(NULL AS int) AS [C7], 
    CAST(NULL AS int) AS [C8], 
    CAST(NULL AS int) AS [C9], 
    CAST(NULL AS int) AS [C10], 
    CAST(NULL AS decimal(18,2)) AS [C11], 
    CAST(NULL AS int) AS [C12], 
    CAST(NULL AS int) AS [C13], 
    CAST(NULL AS int) AS [C14], 
    CAST(NULL AS int) AS [C15], 
    CAST(NULL AS decimal(18,2)) AS [C16], 
    CAST(NULL AS datetime2) AS [C17], 
    CAST(NULL AS int) AS [C18], 
    [Extent8].[ProjectUsageId] AS [ProjectUsageId], 
    [Extent8].[ProjectUsageId] AS [ProjectUsageId1], 
    [Extent8].[ProjectUsageName] AS [ProjectUsageName], 
    [Extent8].[Article_Id] AS [Article_Id]
    FROM  [dbo].[Articles] AS [Extent7]
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[ProjectUsages] AS [Extent8] ON [Extent7].[Id] = [Extent8].[Article_Id]) AS [UnionAll3]
ORDER BY [UnionAll3].[C3] ASC, [UnionAll3].[C1] ASC
```

I cannot believe that this is in any way efficient when it's just supposed to fetch data from 5 tables (which can be nicely joined and have primary keys + relationships defined). The following is the statement which leads to this SQL statement:

```
IQueryable<Article> articles = context.Articles
  .Include("Batches")
  .Include("ScalePrices")
  .Include("Demands")
  .Include("ProjectUsages");

var actualQuery = context.Articles.Where(d => d.DescriptionLong.Contains(searchTermList[0]) || d.Ident.Contains(searchTermList[0]));
```

The tables are defined as follows (example):

```
[Table("Articles")]
public class Article
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Article", ResourceType = typeof(Resources))]
    [StringLength(32), Required]
    public string Ident { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Description", ResourceType = typeof(Resources))]
    [StringLength(4000)]
    public string DescriptionLong { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
[Table ("Batches")]
public class ArticleBatch
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [StringLength(32)]
    public string Barcode { get; set; }

    public decimal Amount { get; set; }
    public ArticleStorageLocation StorageLocation { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return String.Format("{0} ({1}/{2})", Barcode, Amount, StorageLocation);
    }
}
```

The DbContext looks like this:

```
public class ArticleDataDbContext : DbContext
{
    public ArticleDataDbContext(string connectionString) : base(connectionString)
    {
        Database.SetInitializer(new CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<ArticleDataDbContext>());
        this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
        this.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
    }

    public DbSet<Article> Articles { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ArticleBatch> Batches { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ArticleDemand> Demands { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ArticleScalePrice> ScalePrices { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ProjectUsage> ProjectUsages { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Article>().HasMany(d => d.Batches).WithRequired();
        modelBuilder.Entity<Article>().HasMany(d => d.Demands).WithRequired();
        modelBuilder.Entity<Article>().HasMany(d => d.ScalePrices).WithRequired();
        modelBuilder.Entity<Article>().HasMany(d => d.ProjectUsages).WithRequired();
    }
}
```

This is a diagram of the ER Model from within SQL Management Studio:

[image: ER Model]

Do you have any idea if this statement is "correct" or if it is completely nonsense. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: As pointed out in a comment to an answer here you should take a look at the execution plan taken for that query and while you state `I cannot believe that this is in any way efficient when it's just supposed to fetch data from 5 tables (which can be nicely joined and have primary keys + relationships defined)` simply try to build that query on your own and compare its execution plan to the other to see if it really can be built much more efficiently

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Entity Framework creates such a complex query, because the simple query returns a *lot* of duplicate data. Suppose each sub-table contains 10 records for a specific article, and suppose you left-join all four sub-tables on article ID. You've now got a result set of 10*10*10*10 = 10000 rows. Entity Framework's query gives only 1+10+10+10+10=41 rows, but still gives you all the data you asked for.

Per the comments, if the query does cause performance problems, you can split it into multiple separate simpler queries:

```
var articles = context.Articles.Where(d =>
  d.DescriptionLong.Contains(searchTermList[0])
  || d.Ident.Contains(searchTermList[0])).ToList();
// Either loop, or find one specific article for which
// you want to load the details. I'll use a loop.
foreach (var article in articles) {
  article.Batches.Load();
  article.ScalePrices.Load();
  article.Demands.Load();
  article.ProjectUsages.Load();
}
```

You can even wrap this in a serializable/snapshot transaction to ensure data consistency.

Comment: Shouldn't that be the job of the database to figure that out? I suppose the DB will not create the full vector product and then filter but instead filter first and then select the remaining data. Or to put this different: Do you think that this query is "efficient"?

Comment: What does the execution plan tell you? That's all that matters in the end.

Comment: @TomL. If you write a query where the correct result set contains 10000 rows, it doesn't matter how well the query optimizer works, it has to return 10000 rows, or it's got a bug. And those 10000 rows then have to be sent over the network. So yes, I think this query is efficient, at least from that point of view. Your filter is on the article, not on the sub-tables, so if the article matches, the cross-product of all sub-tables would be returned.

Comment: @Khepri That's a large part of it, but not all. If the execution plan shows that the database executes a query in less than a second, but it takes a minute to send the results over the network, you still have to wait a minute before you have the results in your program. :)

Comment: You're of course right, I was just driving more towards the underlying complaint of "this query is really large and I could do this much more efficiently."

Comment: I see where this is going. I just did some tests. Test 1 was with the generated statement. It takes approximately 1500ms according to SET STATISTICS TIME ON. The same statement which yields the same results with "normal" INNER JOINS takes 400ms. So that's nearly a factor of 4.  Is there any way I can tell EF to use a normal JOIN for my data? Also, the execution plan for both statements confirms this. The one for the UNION ALL version looks like crazy, with all kinds of lookups and Hash Sets. I'm not really able to interpret it, but usually the "easier" solution is the better one.

Comment: @TomL. What I do in such cases where the performance problems are measurable, is simply drop the `.Include(...)`, and call `article.Batches.Load(); article.Demands.Load(); ...` afterwards. You can optionally do this in a serializable/snapshot transaction to ensure data is consistent. Would that work for you?

Comment: @hvd: That doesn't sound too bad, I will try this tomorrow.

Comment: @hvd: Great answer. Could you please add it as an answer. I just tried it and it gave a definite performance boost in numbers (300ms + "nearly nothing" for the remaining queries). It is even "feelable" in the UI.